# Visual Studio Release Candidate (RC) update to final

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an MSDN premium subscription. I want to start using Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate, which will be part of that subscription when it is released.

I am wondering, if I install the VS 2015 Ultimate Release Candidate, will I be able to update it to the final release, or will I have to reinstall?

Comment: Not uninstalling beta/rc versions of VS is never not a mistake.  So is installing it on a machine you need to get your job done, fingers crossed you can get rid of it properly.

Comment: The product team has tried to make this a smooth upgrade ever since the first "GoLive" release of Visual Studio 2015. If all goes well, the upgrade will be a smooth experience. In the worst case you'll have to uninstall/reinstall, but I expect it won't be needed.

Comment: Double negatives aside, thanks @HansPassant for the advice. What do you think of jessehouwing's remark?

Comment: I have *way* too many barely healed scars trying to recover my machines from broken un/installers to take much faith in this.   The worst one was installing Win7 on a machine with the 3.5 beta installed, complete disaster.   A scenario that was never tested, the Windows group and the DevDiv group are miles apart.  Will happen again with Win10.  But hey, go ahead, we won't get the "my machine turned into a pile of junk" deluge at SO for another couple of months.  We need a volunteer to kick this off early.

Comment: RC and beta versions of Visual Studio should only be installed on throw-away virtual machines. Unless you enjoy wasting your time.